# How to add input output ports in Microsoft Azure while publishing webservice

Tags: azure, rscript

I have to publish webservice using Microsoft azure, where my packages are installed and my R script is running but when I click on publish as webservice it gives me error saying that "The ports selected for input and output are not valid."